# GRUB and Kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel

I have a simple but important question for my case:
Does upgrading the `Grub` mean upgrading the `kernel` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. GRUB and the kernel are different things and can be upgraded independently of each other.